# How do I properly cast an Ecto.DateTime value to a utc_datetime field?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have multiple Ecto table schemas that include fields of type `:utc_datetime`. When I do a read from one of these tables, I get back `Ecto.DateTime` values for the `:utc_datetime` columns. When creating a changeset using one of these values to write it back into a table, I include a call to `|> cast(params, [:my_utc_datetime_field]` in the function to generate the changeset, but the cast fails with errors set to `[my_utc_datetime_field: {"is invalid", [type: :utc_datetime, validation: :cast]}]`.

I could just manually add function calls to convert the `Ecto.DateTime` values to a different type when I'm creating the changeset, but this seems clunky and error-prone, and I feel like the whole point of `Ecto.Changeset.cast` is to do these kinds of conversions for me. It also feels weird that Ecto is returning an `Ecto.DateTime` value when I query a column, yet that very same value can't be used to write the same data back to the same column.

Is there something I'm missing here? Is this cast failing because I'm trying to do something stupid, or is this functionality just unimplemented as of yet, or...?

I should also note that I'm using a custom third-party database adapter. It has occurred to me that maybe it's not supposed to return `Ecto.DateTime` values for `:utc_datetime` columns in the first place, and maybe the adapter needs to be fixed to convert these columns to a different type. Any clarification that folks can provide here would be really helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, `:utc_datetime` is supposed to return Elixir's new native `DateTime` struct, which will work correctly with `cast`. The problem is probably in the adapter. Can you link to the adapter you're using?

Comment: @Dogbert thanks! I edited our adapter and everything is working great now. It's still very much a work in progress, so we haven't done any big announcement for its release yet or anything, but we did throw the source up here in case you're interested in taking a sneak peak: https://github.com/circles-learning-labs/ecto_adapters_dynamodb